# WordPress built in breadcrumb trail menu?

Tags: menus

Looking for a breadcrumb menu that can be called (preferably from a sidebar widget in header.php) that lists...

Home > Parent Post/Page > Current Page/Post

or alternately...

Home > Parent Category > Current Page/Post

or even

Home > Grand Parent Category > Parent Category > Current Page/Post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Breadcrumb NavXT](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/) will let you do that, it has a built in widget and supports just about everything WordPress can do (breadcrumbs spanning multiple sites in a multi site setup does not work, yet).

Comment: Breadcrumb NavXT FTW :)

Comment: Breadcrumb Navx links are  not clickable, so I don't see the point of it

Comment: What are you talking about? The links are most certainly click-able, you need to double check your settings, and how you are calling the plugin. There are ways to force it to not output links, but the normal usage does output links.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Yoast Breadcrumbs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/breadcrumbs/).  Very well written breadcrumb menu plugin.

[image]

Comment: Not a good recommendation. Please take a look at the code. The only "nice" thing is that he adds his own rss feed widget with his own feed included....

Comment: This plugin hasn't been updated in over 2 years

Answer (score 2):

I use this
http://dimox.net/wordpress-breadcrumbs-without-a-plugin/

you can call it anywhere you want/need a (clickable) breadcrumb trail

Comment: This is also the one that I use and really like.